# Why are empty blocks not all the same size?

Tags: blockchain, block-explorer

Why are empty blocks not all the same size?
On [Monero Blocks](http://moneroblocks.info/) I see a different size for blocks with zero transactions.

1157855 block size 210
1157856 block size 254

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Usually, empty blocks can vary within a couple bytes, as monero amounts (present in the coinbase transaction even in "empty" blocks) are stored in a varying length encoding.

1157856, however, is a lot larger because it's got extra info in the extra field. It's probably been mined by MinerGate, who tends to add their own private information in blocks.

Comment: The amounts in empty blocks is related to the block reward I assume?

Comment: Amounts of what ? If amounts of monero, yes.

Comment: "Amounts of what ?" => Actually I didn't know. I was referring to the amounts in your answer. (by the way; thank you for the quick and useful answers)

Comment: Ah, yes, it is amounts of monero in that case. I will edit for clarity.